# growth of zeta function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory

Consider the zeta function defined on $\mathbb C\setminus\{1\}$. Can one give  an explicit equivalent of $|\zeta|_r=\max_{\substack{s\in\mathbb C\\|s|=r}}|\zeta(s)|$ when $r\to+\infty$.

Comment: At first thought, one may think such a maximum has to be as close as possible to 1, hence on the bissector (not sure of the right term, I mean French "médiatrice") of the segment $[0,1]$, hence on the critical line. There must be references about this.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN The line you refer to is known as the *perpendiculat bisector*, which in the case of $\zeta$ is also known as the *critical line*. Your guess is incorrect though. From the functional equation you know that for fixed $t\neq 0$, as $\sigma\to-\infty$, $|\zeta(s)|$ will grow roughly like $\Gamma(-\sigma)$ (give or take an exponential). In the critical strip, $\zeta$ grows like $O(T)$, much slower than that. The single pole at $1$ has very little to do with $\zeta$'s growth at infinity. To see that, note that subtracting $1/(s-1)$ gets rid of the pole, but doesn't impact growth.

Comment: Thank you for your comment correcting mine. I guess you meant "perpendicular" with a final "r" right?

Comment: Since $\zeta$ has order $1$ we have $\log(|\zeta_r|)=O(r^{1+\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon>0$, and I believe standard complex analysis will easily prove that $\lim_{r\to\infty}\log(|\zeta_r|)/r=\infty$, in other words $|\zeta|_r$ grows faster than $\exp(kr)$ for any $k>0$.